# Bootstrap popover doesn't work when outputed in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When [bootstrap popover](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover_hover&stacked=h) is outputed in `html()` it doesn't work. Only the title is shown. Is there any fix to this?

You can also see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pomegranate3/vmvdqd23/1/)

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
 $("p").html('<a href="#" title="hello, this is title" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</a>');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<p>Click the button to add popover</p>
<button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` call this code after updating html in `<p>` tag. you have to re-initiate after appending/over writing html. You have to add above code inside click event.

Code inside `$(document).ready()` will only works for when page loads. To achieve on dynamically created element, you have to initiate after creating/updating element.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $("p").html('<a href="#" title="hello, this is title" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</a>');
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>Click the button to add popover</p>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The popover should be initiated *after* the button is clicked. The document ready will only load once when the page is loaded.

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $("p").html('<a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</a>');
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLcz90q3/